# Sorting BIG file based on two columns

Tags: java, linux, sorting, external

I have a big file that can't fit in the memory which I would like to sort. The file consists of two columns and multiple records. The first column is numerical type of ~10 digit and the second column of is a string that contains any printing character(to be sorted according to ASCII code).

I need to sort record based on numerical field but in case two records have the same numerical field I would like to sort based on the string i.e. the second column.

For that I am trying to sort using Linux sort which employs external sorting but the problem it does not sort strings based on the ASCII code. Any idea?!!

Comment: Wait, do you mean the problem you have is that numbers are getting sorted alphabetically?

Comment: From what it says in the manual, `sort` should be able to define more than one field, and resolve ties in the first field using the second field. Look for `sort -t : -k 2,2n -k 5.3,5.4` in [here](http://lavica.fesb.hr/cgi-bin/info2html?(coreutils)sort%20invocation).

Comment: Here is an example: the following records should appear sorted as next: Records: 
19328574591456915 QV&6Xr_&u}p4~0!v~&f9D5sy>14wHml2KIX[ 19328574591456915 }A*p>2wN`Cu!2!I>ML`BHr0@=7h-IK?4Db%wQElY#.JN 9643477564 %@!X+D2X'^t(tv+(Zc0sg\Xei@EQJLbz-B 
9643477564 o{Jm9#8a=k~>'H>a{jVdUodTNiEXCV)/::9 

Records(Sorted): 
9643477564 %@!X+D2X'^t(tv+(Zc0sg\Xei@EQJLbz-B 
9643477564 o{Jm9#8a=k~>'H>a{jVdUodTNiEXCV)/::9
19328574591456915 QV&6Xr_&u}p4~0!v~&f9D5sy>14wHml2KIX[ 19328574591456915 }A*p>2wN`Cu!2!I>ML`BHr0@=7h-IK?4Db%wQElY#.JN

Comment: I think the problem is that I have characters like @!#%^&* in my string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GNU sort utility sorts according to the current locale. See the comment from the manpage:

```
   *** WARNING *** The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.
```

You can use the -n flag to do a numeric sort, or the -k to use by a combination of both numeric and non-numeric sorts. For example:

```
sort -k1 -k2n
```

Will do a textual sort according to the first column, then a numeric sort according to the second column.

Comment: Here is an example:
the following records should appear sorted as next:
Records:
19328574591456915 QV&6Xr_&u}p4~0!v~&f9D5sy>14wHml2KIX[
19328574591456915 }A*p>2wN`Cu!2!I>ML`BHr0@=7h-IK?4Db%wQElY#.JN
9643477564 %@!X+D2X'^t(tv+(Zc0sg\Xei@EQJLbz-B
9643477564 o{Jm9#8a=k~>'H>a{jVdUodTNiEXCV)/::9

Records(Sorted):
9643477564 %@!X+D2X'^t(tv+(Zc0sg\Xei@EQJLbz-B
9643477564 o{Jm9#8a=k~>'H>a{jVdUodTNiEXCV)/::9
19328574591456915 QV&6Xr_&u}p4~0!v~&f9D5sy>14wHml2KIX[
19328574591456915 }A*p>2wN`Cu!2!I>ML`BHr0@=7h-IK?4Db%wQElY#.JN

Comment: true but sort -k1 -k2n 
Actually my first comlumn is a numaric and second is string however when sorting based on the string it does not sort based on ASCII code.

Comment: the problem is that I have characters like @!#%^&* in my string

Comment: +1: sort will sort any type of text, even binary (provided it doesn't contain a `\n`) I have no idea why you would want to sort a binary field as its likely to be meaningless.

Comment: @shaklasah If you set `LC_ALL` to the suggested value it will sort properly.